# How to code the path in the <img> tag

Tags: html

The image does not show up. I have used Mac's "Get Info" to see the path.

How do I specify the path in the `<img>` tag?
This is what I have tried:

```
<img class="logo" alt="Help Me" 
     src="../../CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/standout.jpeg"/>
<img class="logo" alt="Help Me" 
     src="users/janedoe/CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/standout.jpeg" />
<img class="logo" alt="Help Me"
     src="~/CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/standout.jpeg"  />
<img class="logo" alt="Help Me"
     src="file:///users/janedoe/CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/standout.jpeg" />
```

I'm Using MacBook Pro (bought in March 2013), Safari is version 6.0.5, OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: You are trying to create an HTML file that is only used locally?  Your first two examples are relative paths.  Can you please tell me what the path is to your HTML file?  We can help you with a relative path if you do.

Comment: The path is: /Users/janedoe/CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/standout.jpeg

Comment: What is the absolute path of your HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<img class="logo" src="file://localhost/users/janedoe/CGT136as/week-07hw/website/images/standout.jpeg" alt="Help Me" />
```

Also check for case sensitive letters

Comment: But why can't i use a relative path? At school on Windows, I can use a relative path: images/standout.jpeg. (??)

Comment: depends "where" you are. Are you in the same directory?

Comment: I tried this absolute path format on MacBook Air, it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a folder called img in the same folder as the index.html is placed in and put all the pictures in the img folder you just have to type /img/"imgname"

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do have the img in the same folder as the index.html. The main folder is website and within folder website I have a folder named images. The index.html is also in the main folder of website.